# Remove specifig part of all URL's in a sheet

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a sheet with multiple links, all in the format of `https://abc.xyz.com/randomstuff` and I would like to remove the `abc.` from all of them.
Is there a way to somehow automate that for me inside google sheets?

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A6:A16, "(https?://)")&
 REGEXEXTRACT(A6:A16, "[^\.]\.+(.+)")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with [Substitute()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094215?hl=en#:%7E:text=SUBSTITUTE%20can%20be%20used%20to,in%20conjunction%20with%20this%20function.):

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"abc.","")
```

[image: Explanation]

Or even use [Arrayformula()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en#:%7E:text=Many%20array%20formulas%20will%20be,array%20formulas%20cannot%20be%20exported.) to apply the formula to a range of values:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A,"abc.",""))
```

[image: arrayformula]